# Get a Value by Key in a JSONArray java android studio

Tags: java, android, json, filter

Please tell me how to print only longt and lati of email address "aaaa@mail.address" with the above json. It is a matter of outputting the value that matches a specific email in the list. This is an expression that goes through a filter and outputs only the list with a specific email value. All lists are output to laloList. This is a program that applies an email filter to laloList and outputs only specific emails.

Please express the expression in detail

```java
public void onCompleted(List<Lalo> laloList) {
    // I consider here is list of latlng from database.
    List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d("wwww", "laloList: " + laloList);

   for (Lalo lalo : laloList) {
        String a = lalo.getLati();
        Log.d("ww", "a: " + a);
        String b = lalo.getLongt();
        String c = lalo.getEmail();
        Log.d("ww", "c: " + c);
        Log.d("ww", "b: " + b);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(a), Double.parseDouble(b));
        latLngList.add(latLng);

   }
```

```json
[
    {
        "num": "34304",
        "email": "aaaa@mail.address",
        "lati": "8888888",
        "longt": "88888888",
        "time": "2022-12-08 21:15:39"
    },
    {
        "num": "34303",
        "email": "aaaa@mail.address",
        "lati": "8888",
        "longt": "88888",
        "time": "8888888"
    },

    {
        "num": "34302",
        "email": "bbbb@mail.address",
        "lati": "8888",
        "longt": "88888",
        "time": "8888888"
    },

    {
        "num": "34301",
        "email": "aaaa@mail.address",
        "lati": "8888",
        "longt": "88888",
        "time": "8888888"
    },

    {
        "num": "34300",
        "email": "cccc@mail.address",
        "lati": "8888",
        "longt": "88888",
        "time": "8888888"
    },
    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("yourJsonArrayResponse".toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                String lati = jsonObject.getString("lati");
                String longt = jsonObject.getString("longt");
            }
```